# Как подключиться к wi-fi через python на windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу написать программу которая могла бы подключаться к wi-fi если известны ssid и пароль.

Comment: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077835/associating-my-windows-computer-to-a-wifi-ap-with-python)
[два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227479/connection-to-wi-fi-using-python)

Comment: Спасибо,но есть одна проблема чтоб так подключаться надо хотя бы один раз подключиться к этой.И потом можно будет сколько угодно раз подключаться.А мне надо подключиться к новой сети то есть в первый раз

Answer (score 1):

Установите это `pip install plumbum`
Затем вот это `pip install winwifi`
Эта команда добавит новый профиль для WiFi и подключится к нему

```
import winwifi
winwifi.WinWiFi.addprofile('ssid_of_router')
winwifi.WinWiFi.connect('the_ssid_of_router', 'password')
```

Отключаем его следующей командой

```
winwifi.WinWiFi.disconnect()
```